# Memory leaks are coming even though object released when parsing facebook response string in fbgraph api

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, memory-management, memory-leaks

Please Help, I am doing an application which will take the response string from facebook fbgraph api and i am parsing the response string like this i'm confused how to overcome memory leaks. I have tried all the ways to my best but i cannot resolve the memory leaks. First time this parsing class executed no leaks are found, leaks are coming when second time it was called and executed when refresh button press. i'm pasting the picture of the memory leaks of the instrument please show me the correct ways of parsing with out memory leaksenter image description here
Here in the code each feed will be saved in the items array object
[image]
[image]
[image]
PLease help

Comment: Did you use the static analyzer? (Product->Analyze, shows you potential memory leaks with object usage trace and so on)

Comment: yes i have used but it is showing no problem in this class

Comment: Also used NSAutoReleasePool yet same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line at the top of your function:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *Pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
```

and add this line at the bottom of your function before "return" statement :

```
[Pool release];
```

May this will help you out.

Comment: Yes i have used that before but the problem is not fixed